# jquery mobile radio buttons controlgroup fluid width

Tags: jquery-mobile, radio-button

What classes I have to overwrite in order to create fluid horizontal radio button in jquery mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "fluid horizontal radio button"?

Maybe [this](http://brooky.cc/2011/04/23/jquery-mobile-cheat-sheet/) can help you, it is a cheat sheet for JQM body elements.

This is an example:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Choose:</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="1" checked="checked" />
        <label for="radio1">option 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" id="radio2" value="2"  />
        <label for="radio2">option 3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" id="radio3" value="3"  />
        <label for="radio3">option 4</label>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup"  data-type="horizontal"  >
        <input type="radio" name="nemprunteurs" id="nemprunteurs1" value="1"  checked="checked">
        <label for="nemprunteurs1">1 emprunteur</label>
         <input type="radio" name="nemprunteurs" id="nemprunteurs2" value="1"  >
       <label for="nemprunteurs2">2 emprunteurs</label> 
</fieldset>
```

resolved

```
#blocemprunteur  .ui-controlgroup-controls { width: 100% !important; }
#blocemprunteur .ui-radio{width:50% !important;}
```